# C++11 compile time calculation of constant array

Tags: c++11, variadic-templates, compile-time-constant

I have class with variadic template parameters like this:

```cpp
template <uint16_t N1, uint16_t N2, uint16_t... Ns>
class TClass
{
public:
  static constexpr std::size_t S = sizeof...(Ns) + 2;
  static constexpr std::array<uint32_t, S> N = {N1, N2, Ns...};
  static constexpr std::array<uint32_t, S> P= /* struggle */;
};
```

Two numeric templates parameters are mandatory and more are optional.

I need to fill the array P at compile time with the following properties:

```
P[0] = 1
P[i] = N[i-1] * P[i-1]
```

So for example when having a class like this:

```cpp
TClass<3,5,9> instance;
```

`instance::N` is filled with the values `{3, 5, 9}`

and

`instance::P` should be filled with the value `{1, 3, 15}`

Any idea how to generate the sequence for P in C++11 code at compile time?

I tried to use some kind of variadic template parameter unpacking but couldn't find a proper solution.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `TClass<3,5,9> instance;`?

Comment: Use a `constexpr` function that calculates and returns the array.  `std::array`, being an aggregate, automatically has an appropriate `constexpr` copy constructor.  Writing that helper function is easier in C++14 and later because of relaxations on the `constexpr` function rules, but it will still be possible in C++11.

Comment: @BenVoigt For C++17 I have a constexpr lambda function which will easily do the job. Unfortunately for support reasons I have to use C++11. Any ideas how it can be implemented in C++11?